# How to update the label of a view from another view?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to update the text of a label in a view B from View A.

```
if (ResultView.getView() == null)
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(MyView.ID);
    ResultView.getView().lblAnalysis.setText("string1");
    ResultView.getView().lblTimeStamp.setText("string2");
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(MyView.ID);
```

The B View doesn't show the change. How can I get the update to display?

Comment: And that relates to eclipse-plugins...how? You may want to retag it to Java.

Comment: Also, if 'getView()' returns null, does that following call populate said View? If not, I'm surprised, that you're not getting a Null-Pointer Exception.

Comment: it is a view in a plugin project. no null-pointer exceptions. I just dont get the label updated in the targeted view,,:(

Comment: Hmm...I never worked with Plugins, I'm afraid. That's why I asked that stupid question. But why do you call that 'showView' function twice? Shouldn't once be enough?

Comment: .showView(VIEWID) would create and/or show the view in the eclipse perspective. First i open to be sure that the Label was instatiated, then I show again to get it visible. If show reset the widgets in there then this might be a cause to my problem